# pass back data with protcols

Tags: ios, objective-c

i need to pass some data to previous view controller, what is problem with my codes?
in this code "contactViewController" is my first view controller and "groupViewController" is my second view controller

```
//ContactEditVC.h (firstViewController)

#import "GroupEditTVC.h"

@interface ContactEditVC : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImageView * imageView;
    UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * takePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * btnGroup;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *groupName;


---------------------------------------------------
//ContactEditVC.m (firstViewController)

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"selectGroup"]){
        //get selected contact


        //pass selected contact to MyContactAppViewController for editing
        GroupEditTVC *destViewcontroller=segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewcontroller.delegate=self;

    }
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.txtFname.text=groupName;

}

- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data
{
   groupName=data;
}
```

and in my second vie controller:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data;
@end

@interface GroupEditTVC : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (retain) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
---------------------------------
//GroupEditTVC.m (secendViewController)


#import "ContactEditVC.h"

@interface GroupEditTVC ()
@end

@synthesize delegate;



- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender {  
    [[self delegate]dataFromController:@"blabla"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. So can you please tell me what is problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some breakpoints in - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender.  Im guessing that [segue identifier] is not equal to what you think it should be and thus it is never going into the block of code inside the if statement.

Comment: i set breakpoint, data in dataFromController method return nil, i don't know why?